# Configuration prooph in Symfony DI Container

Tags: php, symfony, events, cqrs, prooph

I configured all `prooph` `service buses` with `event source` and `event store`.

But it's one thing what make me confused. I must call:
`$eventPublisher = $this->container->get('event_publisher');` in my [CommandBusFactory](https://bitbucket.org/gargi369/lifeorganizer/src/924709d3a31cbeb75bad71b1f70a58a31ee6214d/src/AppBundle/Factory/CommandBusFactory.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)  to glue event emitter and event bus together for dispatching domain event (from Aggregate Root) throught bus to projector. Without this my projections are not called.

My services: [link](https://bitbucket.org/gargi369/lifeorganizer/src/924709d3a31cbeb75bad71b1f70a58a31ee6214d/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Can someone with experience in Symfony DI (Extension and CompilerPass) help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event publisher is not part of your dependency chain. That's the reason why it is not initialized by symfony DI. The event publisher is an `event store plugin` and you have correctly configured symfony DI to call the method `attachToEventStore` but this is not done automatically but only when you request the service from the DI.

To solve the problem you need a factory for the event store that takes a list of plugins and calls the `attachToEventStore` method on each plugin.
The `prooph/event-store-symfony-bundle` contains such a [factory](https://github.com/prooph/event-store-symfony-bundle/blob/master/src/Factory/DefaultEventStoreFactory.php#L39)

Comment: You are right. I added factory for EventStore and at this moment it's working like i want. Thank you! :D